# 'Pods-PubNub-prefix.pch' No input Files

Tags: ios, objective-c, pubnub

I have the following error:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/xxxxxxx/Desktop/xxxxxx/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-PubNub/Pods-PubNub-prefix.pch'
clang: error: no input filesenter code here
```

Pod File

```
platform: ios '8.4'

pod 'Stripe'
pod 'AFNetworking','~> 2.0'
pod 'PubNub', '3.6.8'
pod 'Canvas', '~> 0.1.2'
pod 'CocoaLumberjack'
pod 'AXRatingView', '~> 0.9.6'
```

that I do, I could indicate.
[please explain what you mean here]

Comment: Is it an on-demand booking app? To be specific, Roadyo?

Comment: What does "that I do, I could indicate" mean?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using PubNub 3.6.8 and not 4.1.1?

Comment: What CocoaPods version do you use? Please send output of: `pod --version` command from terminal.